# Legendre Transformation of Landau Free Energy

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ising-model, mean-field-theory

I am trying to get an intuition for the Legendre Transformation of a generic Landau free energy, e.g. for the Ising model with magnetization $m$ given by $$F(m) = \frac{a}{2} m^2 + \frac{b}{4} m^4 + \dots$$ Let's assume we have $a> 0, b> 0$, i.e. we are in the paramagnetic phase.

I now want to Legendre transform to $F(h)$ where $F(h) = F(m) - h m$ with $$h = \frac{\partial F(m)}{\partial m} = a m + b m^3 + \dots .$$ I am now inverting the latter equation order-by-order to get $$m = h/a -  b/a (h/a)^3 + \dots$$

Notice the funny minus sign. Plugging everything into $F(h)$, I get $$F(h) = - \frac{h^2}{2a} + \frac{b h^4}{4 a^2}.$$ I am not sure I understand why the coefficients have different signs. I am thinking that $F(m)$ is concave for all $m$, and so should the Legendre transform (or convex, depending on sign conventions). But it looks like $F(h)$ is neither concave or convex in general, but rather has two minima? Why would that be? Is my math wrong here?

The sign of the first term makes sense to me since from $$m = - \partial F(h) / \partial h = h /a - b h^3/a^4$$ we see that the magnetization is proportional to the magnetic field (to first order) which makes sense. But why does the coefficient of $h^3$ have a negative sign? My guess that there are even higher order terms which will have different signs to correct for this but I would still like to understand what is going on.

Comment: My initial thought was that these negative coefficients eventually lead to $m$ being bounded at large $h$, but then again the mean-field theory should not know anything about $m$ being bounded?

Comment: General mathematical remark: equation $bm^3+am=h$ has, in principle, three roots ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula)). Your method of solving it may play evil trics, particulary at the phase transition (do we stay at the same root?).

Comment: @RogerVadim I don't think that this is the problem here, as he's assuming that both $a$ and $b$ are positive. The problem rather comes from the fact that the computation of $m(h)$ as done here is only valid for small values of $h$. This is clear from the fact that for $h\gg 1$, one has that $m \cong (h/b)^{1/3}$, which is completely different from what comes out of the linearization done here. So, it is not surprising that injecting this inside the formula for $F(h)$ gives a function that has bad properties : it is not the right function except for small values of $h$!

Comment: In particular, it is indeed true that the Legendre transform of a convex function is always a convex function (or concave depending on your sign conventions). For your example, you can check it using the exact expression for $m(h)$ which comes from solving the degree $3$ equation (for instance using wolfram alpha) and injecting the latter inside the formula for $F(h)$.

Comment: OK, I have posted an answer with the relevant pictures to make this clear (hopefully).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the computation of $m(h)$ you are doing  is only valid for small values of h. This is clear from the fact that for $h\gg 1$, one has that $m\approx(h/b)^{1/3}$, which is completely different from what comes out of your small $h$ expansion.
A picture being worth 1000 words, here are both your approximate solution (in green) and the true solution (in black, obtained by solving the third degree polynomial equation), both for $a=b=1$:

[image]

Seeing this, it is not surprising that injecting your expression into the formula for $F(h)$ yields a function that has bad properties: it only coincides with the true function for small values of $h$!
Again, here's a picture: in green, the convex function $F(m)$, in blue the true function $F(h)$ and in orange the function you obtained for $F(h)$:

[image]

As you can see, the true function is concave, as it should be (the Legendre transform of a convex function is always concave with your sign conventions).

Comment: Thank you! I had truncated the expansion at fourth order in $h$ as the Landau free energy is truncated at fourth order as well. But you are of course right, the roots fourth-order polynomial in $m$ have an infinite-order expansion in $h$ …